# Cannot return from main in assembly after a function call

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, return, fasm

I am learning assembly using fasm and I am having trouble returning from main after a function call. With an empty program I can get it to work fine

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code executable

start:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

leave
ret


section '.rdata' data readable
format_str db '%d', 10, 0

section '.idata' data readable import
library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```

but if I add a function call (printf in this case) like so

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code executable

start:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

push esp
push format_str ;set to '%d',10,0 in the data section
call [printf]
add esp, 2*4

leave
ret


section '.rdata' data readable
format_str db '%d', 10, 0

section '.idata' data readable import
library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```

The program will print successfully but will fail to exit the program and crash

What is happening in the function call that causes my return statement to fail and how can I correct for it?

Comment: What OS? How are you compiling/linking? Please post full [MCVE]. Also, what does a debugger say? PS: generally speaking, you should name your entry point `main` if you intend to use C library functions.

Comment: I am compiling on Windows 10. Since you requested, I added the other sections of the code

Comment: Worked fine here. What does the debugger say?

Comment: Don't really know how to use a debugger, I'm installing OllyDbg and I'll try and fugure that out

Comment: @Jester - `generally speaking, you should name your entry point main if you intend to use C library functions` - this is why ?? of course no. can use any name for entry point. `[w]main` need only in case if we link with static crt stub and set entry point to `[w]mainCRTStartup` which internally call `[w]main`. but we can free call export from `msvcrt.dll` without this

Comment: It doesn't hurt to let the C library initialize properly and call your entry point as would normally happen especially if you have mysterious problems. Anyway, that was a general advice before OP even told us he was using windows.

Comment: Especially if you tell it `entry start`  :)

Comment: All I got from the debugger was "Thread 00001FF4 terminated, exit code 7"

Comment: Well, exit code 7 is because you didn't set one explicitly and `printf` returns the number of characters printed which was presumably 7. That's not an error or a crash as such. You can zero `eax` before returning if you wish.

Comment: What if you do a `call [exit]` explicitly instead of doing a `ret`? You' also have to add `exit` to the imports with something like `import msvcrt, printf, 'printf', exit, 'exit'`. I'm just curious if things change

Comment: you need direct call `ExitProcess` if you not use crt

Comment: I direct call to ExitProcess does work, but this seemed like more of a bandaid solution to me. Is it the "correct" solution

Comment: for process exit - somebody must call `ExitProcess` or all threads in process must exit. your option only call `ExitProcess`

Comment: Obviously since the first version works, you do not need to call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: @Jester - no, you mistake. first version work because windows 10 not create additional worked threads here (no dlls used). in second version - `msvcrt.dll` loaded and windows 10 create additional worked threads for load it. `ExitProcess` **mandatory** to call

Comment: Anyway, see how this would have been automatically fixed by using `main` and crt? :)

Comment: That makes sense, tested with a call to my own function (not msvcrt) and it returned without issue, thanks for the help

Comment: @Jester - depend what mean under `automatically` :) of course we can use `entry mainCRTStartup` and implement `main` and add some crt lib. however this can produce another problems with crt

Comment: @rtpax - you not control count of threads in your process - even if you not create threads direct - system can yourself create some working threads in your process (and not only win10) as result your main thread exit, but can still another working threads in process and process not exit. only one solution - call `ExitProcess` - you need or do this yourself or if you use `CRT` - it call `ExitProcess` for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial thread in a process basically looks like this:

```
call LdrLoadAllTheThings ; Might call TLS callbacks etc
call pe_entrypoint ; Your function
push somenumber
call ExitThread ; Exit this thread and possibly the process
```

A process will end after all threads have exited and just returning will work for very simple programs but as soon as somebody calls `CreateThread` or one of the thread pool functions the process will no longer end when you just return, it will stick around as long as there are other threads doing work/waiting. On older versions of Windows it was usually OK for console programs to just return but as you have discovered, it only works because the called functions did not create new threads (relying on internal implementation details). In a GUI program it is even less likely to work and hard to debug because things like `PlaySound` while clicking on a standard UI element might create a thread.

If you build a C/C++ application with the Microsoft toolchain and link with their runtime library then your main function is not the real entry point, the real entry point is mainCRTStartup and it basically works like this:

```
__declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl mainCRTStartup()
{
  int code;
  char*argv;
  int argc = parse(GetCommandLine(), &argv);
  call_constructors();
  code = main(argc, argv); // Your main function
  call_destructors_and_atexit_callbacks();
  ExitProcess(code); // End this thread and all other threads
}
```